# How to call jQuery function from document.ready

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page with jQuery code to scroll to sections of a page.  At the end of each section, I have an up-arrow to scroll to the top of the page -- it works by calling a jQuery function when the arrow is clicked:

```
function JumpTo(location) {
    $("faq_content").mCustomScrollbar("scrollTo", location,{
        scrollInertia:500,
        scrollEasing:"easeOut"});
}
```

When the function JumpTo gets the ID at the top of the page (), it jumps to the top of the page.

At the bottom of the page is this document.ready script to apply a jQuery function to the "faq_content" section:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("faq_content").mCustomScrollbar();
});
```

Everything works perfectly.

Now I want to jump to the top of the page in the document.ready function, so I added the same line I use in sections on the rest of the page:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("faq_content").mCustomScrollbar();
    JumpTo(bkmk00);" 
});
```

That doesn't work.  So I created a separate document.ready function:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("faq_content").mCustomScrollbar("scrollTo", location,{
        scrollInertia:500,
        scrollEasing:"easeOut"});
}
```

So my question is:  why does a jQuery function that works perfectly when called from a button click event not fire on document.ready?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Doesn't work how exactly? An error? Or doesn't do what you expected? It's unclear

Comment: Your line `JumpTo(bkmk00);" ` seems to have missing quotation marks around "bkmk00," and a superfluous quotation mark after the semicolon.

Comment: I doesn't scroll to the top.  I also added console.log("scroll to top") but that message doesn't appear in the dev console, but for the other jQuery functions on the page I do get dev messages like that if I put them in.

Comment: @Heiko Jakubzik - in the anchor links on the rest of the page it appears like this:  onclick="JumpTo(bkmk00);"  I'll try your idea.

Comment: Surprisingly no.  Not even my console.log functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So my question is: why does a jQuery function that works perfectly when called from a button click event not fire on document.ready?

Because **bkmk00** should be a variable containing some value.....

I would suggest, [According to the documentation](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/)......

> **scrollTo**
>
> Usage $(selector).mCustomScrollbar("scrollTo",position,options);

For the position parameter you can choose **top**, **bottom** or an id: '#elefirst' or '#elelast'.

```js
$.mCustomScrollbar.defaults.scrollButtons.enable = true; //enable scrolling buttons by default
$.mCustomScrollbar.defaults.axis = "yx"; //enable 2 axis scrollbars by default


$(".content").mCustomScrollbar();
$('#top').on('click', function (e) {
    $(".content").mCustomScrollbar("scrollTo", "top", {
        scrollInertia: 500,
        scrollEasing: "easeOut"
    });
    //$("faq_content").mCustomScrollbar("scrollTo", '#elefirst');
})
$('#bottom').on('click', function (e) {
    $(".content").mCustomScrollbar("scrollTo", "bottom", {
        scrollInertia: 500,
        scrollEasing: "easeOut"
    });
    //$("faq_content").mCustomScrollbar("scrollTo", '#elelast');
})


//
// call mCustomScrollbar on dom ready
//
$(".content").mCustomScrollbar("scrollTo", "bottom", {
  scrollInertia: 500,
  scrollEasing: "easeOut"
});
```

```css
.content {
    overflow: auto;
    position: relative;
    padding: 20px;
    background: #333;
    margin: 10px;
    width: 740px;
    max-width: 97%;
    height: 400px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.mcustomscrollbar/3.0.6/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.min.css"/>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.mcustomscrollbar/3.0.6/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js"></script>


<button id="top">Scroll top</button>
<button id="bottom">Scroll bottom</button>
<div class="content">
    <p id="elefirst">1</p>

    <p>2</p>

    <p>3</p>

    <p>4</p>

    <p>5</p>

    <p>6</p>

    <p>7</p>

    <p>8</p>

    <p>9</p>

    <p>0</p>

    <p>1</p>

    <p>2</p>

    <p>3</p>

    <p>4</p>

    <p id="elelast">5</p>
</div>
```

Comment: That looks perfect, and it's in the context of Malihu's mCustomScrollbar.  Great work, and thanks very much.

Comment: One followup question.  Your example is from a button click.  I want to call this automatically on page load.  I'm working on that now, but if you have any suggestions it may help a lot.  Thanks again for your answer.

Comment: Great, and thanks.  But I don't see what changed in your code to make it fire on page load.

Comment: Okay, I see that now.  I was looking for a window.onload.  I'll implement that now.  Thanks very much again.